Parameterized Enums in Python
In Python, I want to have an enum-like data structure that can be used like the Option enum in Rust: the enum has parameterized member, and an unparameterized, e.g.,
enum MyType<T> {
    A,
    B(T),
}

would allow me to use MyType.A, MyType.B(1) and MyType.B(2).
What is the most elegant way to achieve this behavior in Python? So far, my only solution would involve subclasses A, B of an abstract class MyType. But the drawback is that this requires me to do instance checking instead of simply using is.
My specific use case is the following: My data can be either replicated across multiple processes or sharded. If it's sharded, I need the number of shards. My function will process data depending on whether it's replicated or sharded.
If enums aren't useful for this, how to better implement this?

You can't. But you can use something akin to tagged unions. https://kobzol.github.io/rust/python/2023/05/20/writing-python-like-its-rust.html

What specific problem is this intended to solve? Please provide a simple python example that shows how it could be used.

@SayandipDutta Thanks for pointing to this great article! I believe, using Union is certainly the way to go here. If you like, you can post a short answer.

As Sayandip Dutta mentioned this article in the comments, where the author Kobzol proposes to use Unions to represent an enumeration of different kinds of objects that represent different instantiations of something (in his case, network packets). This is, in fact, very similar to my problem. So, I ended up representing my data as follows:
@dataclass
class A:
    pass


@dataclass
class B:
    t: T


MyType = Union[A, B]

The disadvantage of this approach is that I have to use isinstance to distinguish between the different instantiations instead of is, which is usually quite costly.

Why do you have to use isinstance? Does your python version not support match-case i.e. structural pattern matching?

Yes, we're still at Python 3.9. In one or two years maybe we'll move a few versions forward.

Python enums are meant to have a fixed membership.  Your example shows an unlimited number of MyType.B(x) members.  This is not a good fit.

So, is there a better way to achieve this?

I'm not a Rust person, so I only have a general idea of what you are doing, which seems to be trying to use Rust's type protection in Python.
